# Sync control flow using nodejs, async, waterfall, each and mysql

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am having some control flow issues using async with mysql and would love some help/advice. Basically, I have an array of items. I want to iterate through the array and, for each item, check if it exists in a MySQL database/table. If the item does not exist, save the item otherwise don't. So the whole use case is synchronous. What I've done is nest async.waterfall inside async.each as I thought async.each would iterate through each item in the array and waterfall would execute functions serially (using data passed as an argument) against each item. But what's happening is that each function is executing for each item and then the next function executes for each item again. Not exactly what I want.

Anyway here's some pseudo-code:

```
var async = require('async');
// Assume that connection established to mysql db using mysql module
var testArray = [1,2,3,4];
var eachCounter = 0;
async.each(testArray, function(item,eachCallback){
    async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        var formattedItem = item + ' some_formatting';
        console.log(item  + ' > ' + formattedItem);
        callback(null, formattedItem);
    },
    function(arg1, callback){
        // Using connection.query here to see if formattedItem exists in a table
        var mysqlRows = 0;
        if(mysqlRows === 0) {
            console.log(arg1  + ' does not exist so save it');
            var insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO ...';
            callback(null, insertQuery, arg1);
        }
        else if(mysqlRows > 0) {
            console.log(arg1  + ' does exist so don\'t save it');
            callback(null, null, arg1);
        }
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback){
        if(arg1 !== null) {
            console.log(arg2  + ' was inserted into mysql table');
            callback(null, 'done');
        }
        else {
            console.log(arg2  + ' was not inserted into mysql table');
            callback(null, 'done');
        }
    }
    ], function (err, result) {
       eachCounter++;
        if(eachCounter === testArray.length) {
             console.log('really done');
        }
    });
    eachCallback();
}, function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log('failed');
    }
    else {
        console.log('success')
    }
});
```

The result is:

```
success
1 > 1 some_formatting
2 > 2 some_formatting
3 > 3 some_formatting
4 > 4 some_formatting
1 some_formatting does not exist so save it
2 some_formatting does not exist so save it
3 some_formatting does not exist so save it
4 some_formatting does not exist so save it
1 some_formatting was inserted into mysql table
2 some_formatting was inserted into mysql table
3 some_formatting was inserted into mysql table
4 some_formatting was inserted into mysql table
really done
```

When what I really, really want is:

```
success
1 > 1 some_formatting
1 some_formatting does not exist so save it
1 some_formatting was inserted into mysql table
2 > 2 some_formatting
2 some_formatting does not exist so save it
2 some_formatting was inserted into mysql table
3 > 3 some_formatting
3 some_formatting does not exist so save it
3 some_formatting was inserted into mysql table
4 > 4 some_formatting
4 some_formatting does not exist so save it
4 some_formatting was inserted into mysql table
really done
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async.each` is done in parallel. You want to use [`async.eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries) to make all your calls run in series.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Unfortunately, switching to eachSeries doesn't help. The waterfall functions inside the eachSeries iterator are still executing in parallel rather than serially.

Comment: oh, I see it. Put your `eachCallback` inside the final waterfall function (not the waterfall array). I think you will still want `eachSeries`. You want to say, "the 'each' is finished when the waterfall is done".

Comment: Ah - that did it! That makes complete sense now. Thanks!